# Firebase Cloud Functions Deploy Error- SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just updated to:

```
npm: 8.11.0
node: v16.15.1
```

**New Edit**:

I just updated again `sudo n latest`:

```
npm: 8.12.1
node: v18.4.0
```

I'm trying to deploy a new cloud function `firebase deploy --only functions:deleteUser`
but I keep getting a cli error:

> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in
> the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs
> to see the error cause

When I look at the log:

> ```
> deleteUser
>
> Detailed stack trace: /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js:84
>
> this.INTERNAL = new FirebaseNamespaceInternals(appStore ?? new lifecycle_1.AppStore());
>
> Provided module can't be loaded. 
>
> Is there a syntax error in your code?
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
>
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js:19:30)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
>
> Could not load the function, shutting down.
> ```

Index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const userID = data.userID;

    admin.auth().deleteUser(userID)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully deleted userID: ', userID);
        return true // without this Return I get a different error: Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error deleting user: ', error);
    });
});
```

**New Edit Again**

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^8.1.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Could you check what's version of Node runtime specified in your functions package.json file, like described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_runtime_options)?

Comment: it says: `"engines": { "node": "12" }`. I'm going to add the entire package.json to the question

Comment: @raina77ow thanks for the tip. I only had to change it to "16" and now it deploys fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to the [tip](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_runtime_options) by @raina77ow in the comments. I had to go inside my `package.json` file and simply change the node version from 12 to 16

old:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12" // causes error
  }
```

new:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16" // error is now gone
  }
```

Comment: In my case I was deploying with serverless, so I also needed to update the `runtime` in the serverless.yml config file to `nodejs16.x`

Comment: 100!  All the links that gcloud cli gave in the terminal were unhelpful at best.  They pointed me to check logging to try to figure out what was wrong with my code - turns out, nothing.  It was actually that Cloud Functions doesn't support the Node version that was originally used in the config when the project was created.

Answer (score 8):

For users in node 12.x version:

```
npm install --save firebase-admin@10.3
```

Comment: This worked for me with docker ubuntu image

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solutions didn't work for me because I already use node version 16. What worked for me was replacing the firebase toolset with the latest version. I was surprised but it cleared the error. You can do that using the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools@latest --force
```

Now be aware that --force shouldn't be used unless you want to really replace the existing toolset (In general some should be careful with that command). Sudo was necessary in my case to execute the command with elevated rights. After that firebase deployment should work.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the Node version from `package.json` as well as the `runtime` from `firebase.json`