# this.INTERNAL = new FirebaseNamespaceInternals(appStore ?? new lifecycle_1.AppStore());

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

I am trying to deploy node.js functions on firebase but getting the below error :

**this.INTERNAL = new FirebaseNamespaceInternals(appStore ?? new lifecycle_1.AppStore());**

The command I tried using to deploy were :

firebase deploy --only functions  // in home directory

firebase deploy --only functions  // in functions directory

but still getting error.
On checking other people experiencing similar issue in the past checked the package.json and can see
"engines": {
"node": "16"
},

error message

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

/Users/akhil/pixNodes/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js:84
        this.INTERNAL = new FirebaseNamespaceInternals(appStore ?? new lifecycle_1.AppStore());
                                                                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/akhil/pixNodes/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js:19:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
```

Comment: my nodejs version is : v12.18.3

Comment: Can you share your code that is throwing the error?

Comment: Hi I am trying to deploy this on firebase so not a specific code that is creating this issue only this error message showing up

Comment: The deployment can fail if something is wrong with your code as well and it's hard to figure out any issue without knowing it.

Comment: you must have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694057/15774176) or comment below it as : deploying with serverless, so  also needed to update the runtime in the serverless.yml config file to nodejs16.x  , is it helpful?

Comment: I came across the same issue and can't figure out what's causing it. @akm did you figure out the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I come across same issue. Updating the node version fixed it. I updated node version to 16